# Clusters in the form of parallel rectangles

Tags: clustering

I have a dataset with 3 features and a pile of quite flat rectangles. My task is perform clustering on this dataset using any clustering method but not hierarchical. I have scaled all features and do kmeans with 6 clusters and got bad result. Tried also to do MDS but I havent enough memory. PCA doesnt work too. It seems that I can use only one feature to separate the data. But I wonder if there is some *clustering* method which can handle this data properly?

Data

[image]

K-means results

[image: ***enter image description here***]

Comment: Cluster on the vertical coordinate only.

Answer (score 2):

Use the one variable only that matters to your problem.

Blindly using all features and scaling them is not the way to go.

Here, I would neither use clustering, nor scaling.

Probably each of the clusters corresponds to a well defined z value. Just use the z value with some rounding if necessary. At most, use some kernel density estimation on Z to find peaks and gaps.

Comment: thx for answer. Actually it is pretty clear to do it in the way you suggested. But what if we had 3 parallel 3 - dimensional subspaces in 4 - dimensional space or even higher dimension? In that example we cant simply plot data, and it would be hard to find good projection. Are there some common techniques for such problems?

Comment: If they are parallel in any way, project the data to the orthogonal vector.

Comment: But there are subspace and **correlation clustering** techniques that even work when you have hyperplanes that are *not* parallel.